# SMTP Mail sending Server Name different from the Sender Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, smtp, smtpclient

I am stuck in a case where SMTP Server is with different name & the sender email has a different name.

```
SMTP Server :- mail.in.xyz.com
Sender :- hrd@in.xyz.com
```

You can note here that Server is `mail.in.xyz.com` and Sender domain is `@in.xyz.com` both are different.

It gives an error :-

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [15384] SecureChannel#57667028 - Remote certificate has errors:
System.Net Information: 0 : [15384] SecureChannel#57667028 - A certificate chain processed, 
but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
```

When it is forwarded to Client :-
The error file refers to one of the certificates(in.xyz.com) which is self-signed.
But it needs to refer to another certificate that is mail.in.xyz.com which is trusted by the XYZ.
Since its referring to self-signed, the mentioned error in log file has occurred.

I am using below code to send mails.

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = data.SMTPServer, // smtp server address here...                    
                    Port = data.PortNo,
                    EnableSsl = data.SSL,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
                    Timeout = 30000,
                };


smtp.Send(message);
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: The server and email address do not need to match. It depends on the email server what parameters to use.   The From address and the credentials have to match.  You do not have a FROM address in your code.

Comment: @jdweng i changed the from & both are matching now but getting same error. 
When i checked the network logs there i found it is using domain of in.xyz.com instead of mail.in.xyz.com. How is it so?
[Issuer]
  CN=in.xyz.com
  Simple Name: in.xyz.com
  DNS Name: in.xyz.com

Comment: Are you on a corporate network with an outlook server?  Does code run on your home computer?  A corporate network forwards SMTP port 587 to a proxy server and has 587 blocked at firewall so you can only go to the corporate network server.  Port forwarding is used.

Comment: @jdweng Code does not work on local computer. Regarding corporate network i have no idea, as it is of client. How can i solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173728/smtp-mail-sending-dns-name-different-in-network-logs

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Email
{
    private const string fromEmail = "mail@site.com";
    private const string webEmail = "webmail.site.com";
    private const string password = "Y2";

    //  Email.Send("x@gmail.com", "blah blah", "HIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII");
    public static void Send(string to, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(fromEmail),
                To = { to },
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
                DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
            };
            using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(webEmail))
            {
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromEmail, password);
                smtpClient.Port = 25;
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
                smtpClient.Send(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception excep)
        {
            throw new Exception(excep.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work.  Most emails server do no use unsecure port 25.