# SMTP Mail sending DNS Name different in Network logs

Tags: c#, .net, email, ssl, smtp

I am using below code to send emails

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = data.SMTPServer, // smtp server address here...                    
                    Port = data.PortNo,
                    EnableSsl = data.SSL,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
                    Timeout = 30000,
                };


smtp.Send(message);
```

SMTP Server :- mail.in.xyz.com

Sender :- hr@mail.in.xyz.com

It is giving me digital signature errors. When i checked in the network logs. It is automatically using a different domain that is not configured in Settings.

```
[Subject]
  CN=in.xyz.com
  Simple Name: in.xyz.com
  DNS Name: in.xyz.com

[Issuer]
  CN=in.xyz.com
  Simple Name: in.xyz.com
  DNS Name: in.xyz.com
```

`in.xyz.com` is self assigned digital signature hence giving error. But i am using `mail.in.xyz.com` in the Settings everywhere.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: First you need a FROM address.  Second you need to use Default Credentials.  Third it probably isn't going to work since this looks like a corporate network. What port number are you using?  When you use default credentials you need to configure POP settings in Control Panel : User Account : Mail.  Do you have an Outlook Account on the Network?

Comment: @jdweng From Address it is specified - hr@mail.in.xyz.com & Port no is 587. Outlook account is there on the Network.

Comment: Then you cannot connected to a third party email server.  Port 587 is blocked going 3rd party email server and is being forwarded to the Outlook Proxy Sever.  You would have to talk to your MIS people to see if anything can be done.  maybe following will work : https://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/faq_79.htm

Comment: @jdweng They are opening TLS while sending the mails.

Comment: TLS is what typically is used for authentication of the credentials.  It has nothing to do with the routing of the port number that is blocking access to third party emails.